# Android Phone Number Verification

Tags: android, sms, whatsapp, phone-number, verification

I need a way to verify that the mobile number set in my Android application is correct as in "ownership" - not data validation of mobile number.

E.g. the way WhatsApp is doing it...

I know how this can be done by SMS verification using codes and stuff. The thing is it's a free Android app and I'm not to keen on paying for every sent SMS when the app is free. Bad business model...

Is there a way to do this safely and free?

Using the API code seem to be not too safe so it's not an option I'm afraid:

```
TelephonyManager tMgr  (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Comment: What do you mean it's "not safe"?

Comment: I don't know how WhatsApp does it, and maybe others here don't know either.  Maybe you could clue us in?

Comment: Actually, in my experience WhatsApp *does* send an SMS verification on account creation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey WhatsApp pulls your number from the OS, sends a text message to the number, and intercepts the text message.

Comment: @Tushar "Not safe" maybe is the wrong word to use here (english not my native language). I really meant _"stable"_ or _"reliable"_ since it often can return `null` and not the phone number.

Comment: @andreas78 What would you do if the user took out their sim card and opened your app? At some point, you'll have to either fail or live with no phone number.

Comment: here http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-adding-sms-verification-like-whatsapp-part-1/ 
AndroidHive Example

Answer (score 21):

WhatsApp does not sent any SMS to you, it sends a SMS with your own mobile phone to your own number. If you receive the SMS everything is OK, if you don't receive a sms you don't own that number. It's the only cheap and easy way to check if a user signed up with their real number.

Comment: This means that the user has to pay for a single SMS?

Any known drawbacks with this solution?

Comment: Yes this is correct. I don't know any disadvantages for this solution

Comment: I've read up a bit on this and it's not very secure.

It seems like WhatsApp struggled with its registration process being insecure.

Several examples of ability to pretend to be an owner of a phone number. :-/

Comment: The only issue is when you don't have any credit left on your mobile phone you can't send any text. If you send the verification SMS with an online free SMS sender you can bypass the security.

Comment: What advantage would a person have to "pretend to be an owner of a phone number"? Is there anything to be gained to cheat here?

Comment: It is not a big deal, it depends on the kind of application you make. If you bypass the security you could easy create spam accounts for example.

Comment: @andreas78 actually that might mean that the user has to pay for two SMS on some networks. US carriers usually charge for incoming texts as well.

Comment: If whatsApp is indeed doing it then it's not ethical as they don't inform if user is sending message to itself and it is costing money. Surprise. Surprise.

Comment: are there any tutorials for this especially in kotlin, most on the web are firebase based verification methods....